# C# SQL Server Relative Path

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'd like my program to reference a relative path to the `.mdf` file so it can run on a new machine without modifying the connection string.

Environment:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.11.8
- Windows Forms

The connection string is pulled from the `dbstring` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sharpening_Teeth
{
    public class dbString
    {
        // modifyTemplate pulls in the connection string from this class
        public static string getConnectionString()
        {
            return "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\vamel\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\test\\Sharpening Teeth\\Sharpening Teeth\\templateDB.mdf";
        }

        public static string getReadQuery()
        {
            return "SELECT template_id, template_name, message_content FROM dbo.message_template";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just getting back into programming and I'm stuck. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction here.  Thank you.

Threads reviewed

- [Connection string with relative path to the database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833640/connection-string-with-relative-path-to-the-database-file)
- [How to set a relative path to a SQL Server Compact database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932963/how-to-set-a-relative-path-to-a-sql-server-compact-database)
- [SQL Express connection string: mdf file location relative to application location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500829/sql-express-connection-string-mdf-file-location-relative-to-application-locatio)
- [connection string with relative path to database not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689683/connection-string-with-relative-path-to-database-not-working)
- [How to set a relative path to a SQL Server Compact database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932963/how-to-set-a-relative-path-to-a-sql-server-compact-database)
- [C# Visual Studio: |DataDirectory| keyword in connection string conflicts mdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974326/c-sharp-visual-studio-datadirectory-keyword-in-connection-string-conflicts-md)

EDIT

I found a solution on reddit.
https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/k0xaqb/local_db_sql_connection_string_without_using_the/

Comment: AFAIK, Connection strings don't accept relative paths (and if you could "relative to ***what***?" would be the operative question).  I'd suggest that you use the technique in your first link.

Comment: To re-emphasize: The first link is the answer to your question.

Comment: Why hard code a connection string? Configuration files have existed since version 1.0

Comment: @MarkBenningfield  Thanks but where would one modifying DataDirectory as executable's path?

Comment: @hurk, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336899/how-is-location-of-data-directory-in-connection-strings-resolved) might be helpful.

Comment: See also [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename) you really shouldn't use it at all, as it's deprecated, I'm not sure why @DavidBrowne-Microsoft is recommending you should use it. Instead attach your database properly using `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH`

Comment: AttachDbFilename is perfectly fine if you're using SQL Server Express LocalDb.  The problems are only with the Service-based install of SQL Server Express.  If you're using that, just attach your databases. Don't use a user instance or AttachDbFileName.